# Any way to know how many bytes will be sent on TCP before sending?

Tags: c++, linux, tcp

I'm aware that the `::send` within a Linux TCP server can limit the sending of the payload such that `::send` needs to be called multiple times until the entire payload is sent.

i.e. Payload is 1024 bytes

`sent_bytes = ::send(fd, ...)` where `sent_bytes` is only 256 bytes so this needs to be called again.

Is there any way to know exactly how many bytes can be sent before sending? If the socket will allow for the entire message, or that the message will be fragmented and by how much?

**Example Case**

2 messages are sent to the same socket by different threads at the same time on the same tcp client via `::send()`. In some cases where messages are large multiple calls to `::send()` are required as not all the bytes are sent at the initial call. Thus, go with the loop solution until all the bytes are sent. The loop is mutexed so can be seen as thread safe, so each thread has to perform the sending after the other. But, my worry is that beacuse Tcp is a stream the client will receive fragments of each message and I was thinking that adding framing to each message I could rebuild the message on the client side, if I knew how many bytes are sent at a time.

Although the call to `::send()` is done sequentially, is the any chance that the byte stream is still mixed?

Effectively, could this happen:

- Server Side

  - Message 1: "CiaoCiao"
  - Message 2: "HelloThere"
- Client Side

  - Received Message: "CiaoHelloCiaoThere"

Comment: for my interest - why do you care?

Comment: @pm100 I've made my own Tcp server/client code and will have multiple threads sending information which may cause fragmented messages. I have basic framing to specify the number of total bytes present in the message, but in the case where two messages sent  to the same socket overlap/merge there needs to be a way to rebuild the message on the client. So the idea, similar to WebSocket, is to use framing and it would be veerryy handy to know upfront if a message will be fragmented and by how much. Not sure if that makes sense outside of my brain

Comment: just because you send the message all in one chunk is no guarantee that it wont get fragmented by routers, gateways, and the client side stack. ... You just have to deal with the fact that TCP only offers 2 gurantees, the bytes arrive in the correct order, they arrive only once

Comment: @pm100 Hmmm I didn't consider this, I thought they would have been transmitted as a 1500 or so byte packet as ethernet does. I assumed it would have stayed in this packet size but yes even then things could get jumbled getting to the client. I may have to rethink my approach.

Comment: There cannot possibly be anything like this, for a very simple reason. Supposing that the kernel might be capable of sending `N` bytes on a particular socket at any given time, this gives absolutely no guarantees whatsoever that this will remain the same a single clock tick later. Anything can happen. More kernel memory is now used, by various  kernel functions. If a socket shares a common memory/buffer pool, it can now be used up. The kernel might've received an ICMP message, related to the socket's peer, that notified it that the peer is now unreachable, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: What is the ***real*** problem you're trying to solve? No, not the one about knowing how many bytes can be sent on a socket at any given time, but the problem to which you believe the solution involves knowing how many bytes can be sent on a socket at any given time, so this is what you're asking about. But if you can formulate what the real question is here, it's very likely that a completely different solution will be possible.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You are right, I will edit the question to be a little bit more specific

Comment: Things wont get 'jumbled' TCP guarantees the ordering of bytes

Comment: Jumbled in the sense that the received message will be the "beast with two backs" from two originally individual messages

Comment: Simplest approach is it length prefix each message and then you know on the receiving end how many bytes to reassemble for each message,  You don't have to worry about message termination byte(s) needing to be escaped if they could be included in the message body.

Comment: @RichardCritten This approach has already been implemented and is working, the case is when the messages are large enough to be fragmented by the Tcp socket and multiple messages are sent, making this feature/framing kind of redundant

Comment: Which means you have not correctly implemented the receiver. You need to keep looping receiving until you have got a whole message

Comment: The receiver uses this framing to read the bytes of the message that was sent, as I said this functionality is alreayd in place and working. My question is wont there be an issue of mixed messages due to sending to the same socket at the same time by the server? So the received message although framed/payload size given could be a mix of two messages?

Comment: The client side receive knowns nothing above TCP/IP frames, it can read any amount of data from 1 byte, to part of a frame, or many frames.

Comment: @RichardCritten I know, thats why I provide the amount of bytes in the payload at the start of the message, so that the client knows how much data to read

Comment: So the client keeps reading from the socket until it has built a complete message (and keeps any extra data it has read for the next message).

Comment: @RichardCritten I know how Tcp works, I know it works as a stream. I've edited the question above to provide an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Although the call to ::send() is done sequentially, is the any chance that
> the byte stream is still mixed?

Of course. Not only there's a chance of that, it is pretty much going to be a certainty, at one point or another. It's going to happen at one point. Guaranteed.

> sent to the same socket by different threads

It will be necessary to handle the synchronization at this level, by employing a mutex that each thread locks before sending its message and unlocking it only after the entire message is sent.

It goes without sending that this leaves open a possibility that a blocked/hung socket will result in a single thread locking this mutex for an excessive amount of time, until the socket times out and your execution thread ends up dealing with a failed `send()` or `write()`, in whatever fashion it is already doing now (you are, of course, checking the return value from send/write, and handling the exception conditions appropriately).

There is no single, cookie-cutter, paint-by-numbers, solution to this that works in every situation, in every program, that needs to do something like this. Each eventual solution needs to be tailored based on each program's unique requirements and purpose. Just one possibility would be a dedicated execution thread that handles all socket input/output, and all your other execution threads sending their messages to the socket thread, instead of writing to the socket directly. This would avoid having ***all*** execution thread wedged by a hung socket, at expense of grown memory, that's holding all unsent data.

But that's just one possible approach. The number of possible, alternative solutions has no limit. You will need to figure out which logic/algorithm based solution will work best for your specific program. There is no operating system/kernel level indication that will give you any kind of a guarantee as to the amount of a `send()` or `write()` call on a socket will accept.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, after discussing this above I also came to the conclusion of using a dedicated thread to send the messages and other threads simply send their messages to that one. So it's quite nice to see some idea convergence, I will ponder on the matter further as there are numerous solutions to the matter